# How can i remove the location updates

Tags: android

Because of min time betwwen update it display the location update after 1 sec again and again how can i sttop this once i get the location update

```
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1000; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1*1000*60; // in Milliseconds
protected LocationManager locationManager;


LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);



private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
     {

         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
         {
             String message = String.format(
                     "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                     location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(),location.getTime()
             );
             Toast.makeText(MyService.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

         public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {}

         public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}

         public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

For removing updates you have to call

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(<yourLocationListener>);
```

Comment: i have call this method inside my Onloactionchange but it forcefully closes the application

Comment: you should call it in onDestroy method.

Comment: Where should i create a  destroy method  inside MyLocationListener class or outside ?

Comment: `public void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy()}` directly in your Activity class, you need to override this method but you accepted @Niek so ask him.

Comment: The time at which i receive me location update through location.getlatitude n longitude

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
 locationManager= null;
```

Comment: Can you post you logCat output??